# change the textview style in androidstudio

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-arrayadapter

I have created a listview called popuplistfragment.java and list_view.xml.I have added textview in xml file but I dont know where to add code to change the textview in the listview.

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PopupListFragment extends ListFragment implements      OnItemClickListener {

TextView textview;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),  R.array.quotes, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Log.v("check", "item is clicked");


    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SwipeViews.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("key", item);
    myIntent.putExtra("index", position);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

}
```

And this is the list_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:background="@drawable/back_listview">
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:longClickable="false"

    >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:textColor="#e15258"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to extend Adapter class

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
   String [] mQuotes;
   public ListAdapter(String [] quotes){
      mQuotes = quotes;
   }
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View v = convertView;
       if (v == null) {
           LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
           v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);
       }
       TextView quoteTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.quote_textView);
       quoteTextView.setText(mQuotes[position])
       return v;
   }

   @Override
      public int getCount() {
         return quotes.length;
      }
}
```

Then implement other methods.
The next step is to change next code

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String [] QuoteArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quotes);
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(QuoteArray);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Then add itemlistrow.xml to Layout folder and change it so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/quote_textView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can customize itemlistrow.xml as you want