# Programmatically hightlight ListView items

Tags: android, listview

I want highlight the first element of my listview programmatically, when the Activity is created.

The highlight options of my ListView are:

```
<item name="android:choiceMode">singleChoice</item>
<item name="android:listSelector">@color/green</item>
```

I tried a lot of methods to initialiaze the highlight, all not working.

```
- list.setSelection();
- list.setItemChecked();
- list.performItemClick();
- maybe other...
```

Why is so painfull highlighting a ListView item from code? What I should know?

Comment: You could additionally try `View child = listView.getChildAt(0)` and `child.requestFocus()` maybe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically select item ListView in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788688/programmatically-select-item-listview-in-android)

Comment: Yes, but what I'm searching is a clean way to highlight. The linked solution (in my opinion) isn't so clean. No?

Comment: Do you want a clean solution or a working solution? `Mylistview.setItemChecked(position, true);` isn't clean?

Answer (score 0):

use custom adapter and in onBindViewHolder user as

```
if(position == 0){
//set highlight code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087718/4777972)

And in getView method add

```
if(position == 0)
   // set background color for View
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your Custom adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      //Initialize view holder
    switch(position) {
    case 0: {
      //Highlight view
            break;
         }
           default: {
           //Rest of List items
           }
      }
```

Comment: `list.setSelection` is different than drawing a custom background